# How to join VLOOKUP results of multiple sheets into one cell

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I am trying to use `TEXTJOIN` across multiple sheets, IF a cell is is the same I would like it to return the value from another cell in all sheets that are associated with it.

In this example, I am trying to look up the value on Sheet1 and Sheet2 for **code** in $B$4:$B$7 **22155**... and to retrieve the associated $D$4: $D$7 **AAA** and/or **BBB** and `TEXTJOIN` them " - ".

I have tried `TEXTJOIN` and combining the IF and also VLOOKUP but my brain just can't seem to work it out. This will be along a larger range of sheets and 100+ **CODES** in each sheet.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: The desired outcome is to link the different Model to the Code. in the end I would like to have a Code with what model is  this Code is associated with. I have made an example on the right with 22155.

Answer (score 0):

- **to get all unique codes:** 


  ```
  =UNIQUE({QUERY(QUERY(B3:B, "select *", 0), "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0);
           QUERY(QUERY(F3:F, "select *", 0), "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0)})
  ```
- **to get (joined) text per every unique code:**


  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(
   "×"&IFERROR(VLOOKUP(J3:J, B3:D, 3, 0), )&" - "&
       IFERROR(VLOOKUP(J3:J, F3:H, 3, 0), )&"×", 
                "×* - *×", ""), 
                "× - "   , ""), 
                "×"      , ""))
  ```

[image: 5]